# Large percent of requests in CLRThreadPoolQueue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, azure, signalr, azure-web-app-service

We have an ASP.NET MVC application hosted in an azure app-service. After running the profiler to help diagnose possible slow requests, we were surprised to see this:

[image: Profiler Result]

[image: Slow Requests]

An unusually high % of slow requests in the CLRThreadPoolQueue. We've now run multiple profile sessions each come back having between 40-80% in the CLRThreadPoolQueue (something we'd never seen before in previous profiles). CPU each time was below 40%, and after checking our metrics we aren't getting sudden spikes in requests.

The majority of the requests listed as slow are super simple api calls. We've added response caching and made them async. The only thing they do is hit a database looking for a single record result. We've checked the metrics on the database and the query avg run time is around 50ms or less. Looking at application insights for these requests confirms this, and shows that the database query doesn't take place until the very end of the request time line (I assume this is the request sitting in the queue).

Recently we started including SignalR into a portion of our application. Its not fully in use but it is in the code base. We since switched to using Azure SignalR Service and saw no changes. The addition of SignalR is the only "major" change/addition we've made since encountering this issue.

I understand we can scale up and/or increase the minWorkerThreads. However, this feels like I'm just treating the symptom not the cause.

Things we've tried:

- Finding the most frequent requests and making them async (they weren't before)
- Response caching to frequent requests
- Using Azure SignalR service rather than hosting it on the same web
- Running memory dumps and contacting azure support (they
  found nothing).
- Scaling up to an S3
- Profiling with and without thread report

-- None of these steps have resolved our issue --

**How can we determine what requests and/or code is causing requests to pile up in the CLRThreadPoolQueue?**

Comment: Here are a few ideas: 1-set always on to true, review the async methods and also check if there are Task.Factory in your code. Take a look on the following link too

https://azure.github.io/AppService/2018/06/06/App-Service-Diagnostics-Profiling-an-ASP.NET-Web-App-on-Azure-App-Service.html

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio - It's already on, async methods were added in an attempt to fix the issue, found no Task.Factory but did find a few Task.Run however my tracing says they aren't executed very often.

Comment: Hi @Sen. Have you found something on this? We are experiencing something like this, which seems "threadpool starvation". Does anyone have any idea on how to find the call(s) that's causing it in Azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We encountered a similar problem, I guess internally SignalR must be using up a lot of threads or some other contended resource.

We did three things that helped a lot:

1. Call `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(400, 1)` on app startup to make sure that the threadpool has enough threads to handle all the incoming requests from the start
2. Create a second App Service with the same code deployed to it. In the javascript, set the SignalR URL to point to that second instance. That way, all the SignalR requests go to one app service, and all the app's HTTP requests go to the other. Obviously this requires a SignalR backplane to be set up, but assuming your app service has more than 1 instance you'll have had to do this anyway
3. Review the code for any synchronous code paths (eg. making a non-async call to the database or to an API) and convert them to async code paths